# Webpack mini-css-extract-plugin doesn't include my scss during the bundling process

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I have a React application where I'm trying to include some sass. 
I'm also using Webpack to bundle all my .scss files into a single .css file for production.
To do so, I use the mini-css-extract-plugin, but my all my style files aren't bundled into the final output file even though they're imported in my app.js below. Only my .scss files from my app.js are loaded correcty in the bundle but not my `styles.scss`. So my styling is working in the development stage but not when I'm deploying for production.

Here is the command I run when I want to build my app (in my package.json file).

```
"build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.js ./src/app.js --output ./dist/bundle.js"
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  }
});
```

**webpack.common.js**

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      favicon: './public/images/favicon.ico'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    })
  ]
};
```

**src/app.js**

```
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import './styles/styles.scss';
```

**src/styles/styles.scss**

```
@import './base/settings';
@import './base/base';
@import './components/_button';
@import './components/_header';
@import './components/_content-container';
@import './components/_page-header';
@import './components/_input-group';
@import './components/_inputs';
@import './components/_form';
@import './components/_list';
```

**Webpack output**

```
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html 217 bytes {0} [built]
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
       2 modules
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!node_modules/react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
       2 modules
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!src/styles/styles.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/styles.scss 3.66 KiB {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

Comment: Try and wrap your styles into one file for production `new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/style.css?[hash]",
            allChunks: true
        }),`  and include `import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';` into `styles.css`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change much except that the file is not minified anymore. I actually figured out that only `'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css'` is bundled.

Comment: try removing OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin and splitting the css/scss loader rule into css and scss separatly.

Comment: Doesn't change neither